# Can we pass two functions as an argument in another function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm new to JavaScript. We can pass two variables and arrays as a arguments of a function, and can pass a function as a argument in another function, but can we pass 2 functions as an argument in another function like below.

```js
var years = [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000];

function age(array1, fn) {
    var age = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        age.push(fn(array1[i]));
    }
    console.log(age);
}

function calculateAge(yearOfBirth) {
    return 2019 - yearOfBirth;
}

age(years, calculateAge);

function yearsForRetire(years, calculateAges) {
    var yearsForRetire = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
        yearsForRetire.push(65 - calculateAges(years[i]));
    }
    console.log(yearsForRetire);
}

function any(age, yearsForRetire) {
    //body
}
```

Comment: You are not passing two functions as an argument anywhere in that code. But yes - you can, if you want. Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: Yes, what are you specifically trying to do?

Comment: of course you can, I don't see what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass functions as arguments of another function. Here is a very simple example to explain the working:

```
function a() {
    return 'xyz';
}

function b(a) {
    console.log(a())
}

b(a)
```

Output :

```
'xyz' // This is the result from function a
```

Comment: VLAZ and haopeng, Thanks for letting me know i got a bit confused, I have edited the answer is this correct?

Comment: @pavanskipo yes, it is